# Can I sort the output of ip address?

Tags: sort, iproute

I have a router with a few hundred network interfaces (most of which virtual, naturally).  That means that the output of

```
ip a
```

shows very many lines which makes management and analysis difficult.  Items 1 to 255 are sorted by item number but from 256 the numbers are calculated mod 256 before sorting them which means they are interleaved (e.g. 256, 257, 1, 258, 2, ...):

```
# ip a s up
256: veth-99-02@br-vxlan-99-02: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:99:88:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.99.254/24 scope global veth-99-02
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
257: vxlan-22-01: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master br-vxlan-20-01 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:99:88:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
258: br-vxlan-22-01: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:99:88:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:99:88:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Is there a way to correctly sort this output by number?  (They are multi line entries so `| sort -n` won't do.)

Or, can I select to display numbers e.g. up to 42?

I tried to select by type (`ip a s type ...`) but that does not really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an option that outputs the information each in separate line `-o`:

> -o, -oneline
> output each record on a single line, replacing line feeds with the '\' character. This is convenient when you want to
> count records with
> wc(1) or to grep(1) the output.

so `ip -o a s up |sort -n` should do the job; you can then convert back those backslashes to newlines `ip -o a s up |sort -n |tr '\\' '\n'` if it was needed.

seems when using `-o` option, it drops some information (I don't know why); then you can use below awk preprocessing alternative before passing to the sort command:

```
ip a s up \
| awk '{ printf "%s" (NR>1 && /^[0-9]+:/?"\0":(NR>1?"\n":"")) $0 }' \
| sort -nz \
| tr '\0' '\n'
```

that is adding null character between each block of interfaces, and then using sort with `-z` sorts the input of null delimited records, and finally revert those null characters back to newlines with `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```bsh
ip a s up | gawk '
  match($0, /^([0-9]+): /, m) {
    if (prev) ip[prev] = lines
    prev = m[1]
    lines = ""
  }
  { lines = lines $0 RS }
  END {
    if (prev) ip[prev] = lines
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (num in ip) print ip[num]
  }
'
```

Comment: The quoting of newlines is shell specific (and doesn't work in mine) but otherwise it works, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand: quoting of what newlines? Do you mean the multi-line string in single quotes? What shell can't do that?

Comment: The `tcsh` does not handle it. Its syntax is C-oriented so you need to end a line in a backslash in order to carry on the command in the next line. There may be other shells that cannot handle the single quote handling of newlines but I don't know many.